# Why do I get Syntax error "}" unexpected in building Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh

When I try to build Dockerfile with this line of code:

```
RUN modifyPermissions() {if [ -n "${OWNER}" ]; then \
                           chown "${OWNER}":zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt;\
                         else\
                           chown 1001:zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt;\
                         fi\
                        }
```

I have this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

Looks like the problem is in last curly bracket but I can't understand why.
Please help! Tnx!

Comment: Why are you declaring a shell function in a Dockerfile? Couldn’t you just run `if [ -n "${OWNER}" ] ; …`? Or even just `RUN chown "${OWNER:-1001}":zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt`?

Comment: Try a space after `{`

Comment: A shell function will exist for the duration of that shell, which in this case will be discarded at the end of the RUN step. This is unlikely to have your desired result when you fix the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, according to the comments, the most important thing is not to declare the functions in Dockerfile. I thought to use the functions but you do not recommend it in the comments. I have a lot of code that I thought to divide into functions for clearer execution and that my code does not repeat itself.

Comment: I try adding space after { . Got error: /bin/sh: 1: [[: not found   /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the original syntax error is that `{` must be followed by whitespace. This would be syntactically correct:

```
RUN modifyPermissions() { if [ -n "${OWNER}" ]; then \
                           chown "${OWNER}":zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt;\
                         else\
                           chown 1001:zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt;\
                         fi\
                        }
```

But as folks pointed out in the comments, each `RUN` command executes in a separate shell, so functions, variables, etc, defined in one `RUN` statement won't be available to others. The only way a function like this would be useful would be if you used the function within the same `RUN` script:

```
RUN modifyPermissions() { if [ -n "${OWNER}" ]; then \
                           chown "${OWNER}":zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt;\
                         else\
                           chown 1001:zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt;\
                         fi\
                        }; \
                        modifyPermissions
```

...and in the case, you haven't saved yourself any effort; you might
as well simplify the entire thing to:

```
RUN chown "${OWNER:-1001}":zagrebgroup -R /var/log/app /mnt
```

That accomplishes the same thing in a much simpler fashion.